# Find $c$ such that $ 0.05 = P \left( \sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i \geq c \right) $

Tags: probability, statistics

I have to solve, for $c$, the equation

$$
0.05 = P \left( \sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i \geq c \right)
$$

where $X_i~~ i.i.d  \operatorname{Poisson}(1) \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(10) $.

If the random variables were continuous I could calculate $c$ from the complement $0.95 = P(\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i \leq c)$ but that is not the case.

Comment: You are just asking for $c$ such that $P(\text {Poisson}(10)≥c)=.05$?  I'd just do it numerically.  You only need to compute a few values.

Comment: How would one do that? I don’t know.

Comment: Just compute a few values.  What is the probability that $\text{Poisson}(10)>0$?  That it is $>1$?  and so on.  Just stop when you have a number less than $.05$   You can save a little time if you note that the answer is surely greater than $10$ but, of course, it isn't all that much greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the random variables were continuous I could calculate cc from the complement

of course you can also in a discrete case! in any case the probability over all the support is 1.

Easy find $C=16$.

To speed up the calculation (I did it with a poket calculator)

$P(X=14)>0.05$ (14 is not good)

$P(X=15)=0.035$ (mmmh...let's see the next)

$P(X=16)=0.022$ (15 is not good)

The other values over $X=17$ have all a probability close to zero....Thus $C=16$

Verify with a Calculator but I'm sure it is correct!